# how to use correctly useQuery (apollo client) in React with dependencies in local storage?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I need some help. I'm development an user dashboard app with NextJS and GraphQL. The app is compounded by four sections, some of these sections are dependents on certain data stored in the browser local storage.

When the client is logged, in this process exists a custom hook that fetches data to be rendered in the home section and then stores some of this data in the browser local storage. The problem occurrs when I need to render other sections which depends of the data stored in the local storage, when I run the app in dev mode, everything works fine, but not in prod the app crashes.

this is the component file

```
export default function UserDataUsage() {

  let services, user
  if (isWindowAvailable) services = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("services"))
  if (isWindowAvailable) user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
  CheckLocalStorage(user)
  const { ciRif } = user
  const defaultService = services[0]["id"]
  const [service, setService] = useState(defaultService)
  const textColor = useColorModeValue("secondaryGray.900", "white");

  const { data: { contractDetails, dailyDataUsage, monthlyDataUsage, monthlyHistory, allServices }, error, loading } = useDataUsage(service, ciRif)

  if (loading) return <Spinner />

  const { plan } = contractDetails

  return (
    <Box pt={{ base: '130px', md: '80px', xl: '80px' }}>

      <>
        <SimpleGrid
          columns={1}
          gap='20px'
          mb='20px'
        >
          <Text
            color={textColor}
            fontSize='22px'
            fontWeight='700'
            lineHeight='100%'>
            Contratos
          </Text>
          <Select
            fontSize='sm'
            fontWeight='700'
            value={service}
            onChange={(e) => setService(e.target.value)}
          >
            {
              services.map((service) => {
                return <option key={service.id} value={service.id}>Contrato #{service.id}</option>
              })
            }
          </Select>
          <Text
            color={textColor}
            fontSize='22px'
            fontWeight='700'
            lineHeight='100%'>
            {plan}
          </Text>
        </SimpleGrid>

        <SimpleGrid
          columns={{ base: 1, md: 2, lg: 3, '2xl': 5 }}
          gap='20px'
          mb='20px'
        >
          <ContractDetails contractDetails={contractDetails} />
        </SimpleGrid>

        <SimpleGrid columns={{ base: 1, md: 2, xl: 2 }} gap='20px' mb='20px'>
          <TotalSpent monthlyHistory={monthlyHistory} />
          <DailyTraffic dailyDataUsage={dailyDataUsage} />
        </SimpleGrid>
        <SimpleGrid columns={{ base: 1, md: 1, xl: 2 }} gap='20px' mb='20px'>
          <DataUsage
            columnsData={columnsDataUsage}
            tableData={allServices}
          />
          <PieCard monthlyDataUsage={monthlyDataUsage} />
        </SimpleGrid>
      </>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

this is the custom hook

```
const useDataUsage = (service, ciRif) => {

    const { data: dataUsage, error: errorDataUsage, loading: loadingDataUsage } = useQuery(USER_DATA_USAGE, { variables: { serviceId: Number(service) } })
    const { data: dataServices, error: errorServices, loading: loadingServices } = useQuery(SERVICES, { variables: { ciRif } })

    const date = new Date()

    let contractDetails, monthlyDataUsage, monthlyHistory, dailyDataUsage, allServices

    if (!loadingDataUsage && !loadingServices) {

        const { services: _services } = dataServices
        const { services, dailyDataUsage: _dailyDataUsage, monthlyHistoryDataUsage } = dataUsage
        const { idPlan: { download, upload, cap, plan }, dataUsage: { dataUsage: monthDataUsage } } = services[0]


        dailyDataUsage = _dailyDataUsage.map((_day) => {
            const { day, dayname, dataUsage: dayDataUsage } = _day
            return {
                day,
                dayname,
                dayDataUsage
            }
        })

        contractDetails = {
            download,
            upload,
            cap,
            plan,
            monthDataUsage,
            availableQuota: ((cap * 1000) - monthDataUsage)
        }

        monthlyDataUsage = {
            month: date.getMonth() + 1,
            monthDataUsage,
            cap: (cap * 1000)
        }

        monthlyHistory = monthlyHistoryDataUsage

        allServices = _services.map((service) => {
            const { id, idPlan: { plan, cap }, dataUsage: { dataUsage } } = service

            return {
                id,
                plan,
                quota: (cap / 1000000).toFixed(2),
                dataUsage: (dataUsage / 1000000000).toFixed(2),
                status: dataUsage >= (cap * 1000) ? "ACTIVO - LIMITADO" : "ACTIVO"

            }
        })
    }

    return { data: { contractDetails, dailyDataUsage, monthlyDataUsage, monthlyHistory, allServices }, error: errorDataUsage || errorServices, loading: loadingDataUsage || loadingServices }

}
```

I have tried to solve this problem by implementing useEffect inside the custom hook to wait for the data that comes from local storage but this keeps causing errors, at the moment I can't find an explanation why the application runs correctly only in development

Comment: What is in the `isWIndowAvailable` variable? `services` isn't set if that is false and then you'll error out at `const defaultService = services[0]["id"]`